# Java: Acceder a los miembros de una subclase desde una variable local del tipo de la superclase

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Tengo una clase padre ´Electrodomestico´ de la que heredan otras dos subclases ´Lavadora´ y ´Televisor´. En el método principal creo un vector para elementos de tipo ´Electrodomestico´ y en cada posición asigno una instacia de alguna de sus subclases .

Dependiendo del tipo de la instancia de cada posición de arreglo, necesito obtener un dato de una u otra clase a través de sus propiedades. Estoy utilizando según la condición para lo que utilizo el operador ´instanceOf´ para determinar a que clase pertenece cada elemento del arreglo, pero no tengo manera de acceder a un método propio de la clase hija, sólo me muestra los de la clase padre. Copio el código del main para ser más clara.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Crea un array de Electrodomesticos de 10 posiciones.
Electrodomestico listaElectro[]=new Electrodomestico[10];
float sumaLavar=0;
//Asigna a cada posición un objeto de las clases anteriores con los valores que desees.
listaElectro[0]=new Lavarropas(35,250,"blanco",'F',63);
listaElectro[1]=new Lavarropas(15,120,"negro",'A',50); 
listaElectro[2]=new Lavarropas(31,270,"blanco",'F',63);
listaElectro[3]=new Lavarropas(35,250,"violeta",'B',50);
listaElectro[4]=new Lavarropas(35,250,"rojo",'C',63);
listaElectro[5]=new Television();
listaElectro[6]=new Television(45,true,562,"gris",'f',50);
listaElectro[7]=new Television(90,false,562,"blanco",'a',100);
listaElectro[8]=new Television(22,true,520,"gris",'d',20);
listaElectro[9]=new Television(29,true,562,"rojo",'f',50);
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    System.out.println("Precio final: "+i+" "+listaElectro[i].precioFinal()); 
    
    if (listaElectro[i] instanceof Lavarropas){
        Aquí quisiera acceder al método getCarga() que se encuentra en Lavarropas
       // sumaLavar=sumaLavar+listaElectro[i].precioFinal();
    }
   
}
 System.out.println("Total Lavarropas: "+sumaLavar);

}
```

Electrodomestico

```
public class Electrodomestico {

protected final static String COLORCONST="Blanco";
protected final static char CONSUMOCONST='f';
protected final float PRECIOCONST=100;
protected final static float PESOCONST=5;

protected float precioBase;
protected String color;
protected char consumo;
protected float peso;

public Electrodomestico() {
}

public Electrodomestico(float precioBase, float peso) {
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
    this.peso = peso;
}

public Electrodomestico(float precioBase, String color, char consumo, float peso) {
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
    this.color = color;
    this.consumo = consumo;
    this.peso = peso;
}
 public float getPrecioBase() {
    return precioBase;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public float getConsumo() {
    return consumo;
}

public float getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

private void comprobarConsumoEnergetico(char letra){
    if ((letra>65 && letra<71)||(letra>97 && letra<102)){
            this.consumo=letra;
    }
            else{
                    this.consumo=CONSUMOCONST;
            }
}

private void comprobarColor(String color){
    String vectColor[]={"blanco", "negro", "rojo", "azul", "gris"};
    boolean encontrado=false;
    for (int i=0; i<vectColor.length && encontrado==true; i++) {
        if (color.equals(vectColor[i])){
            encontrado=true;
        }
    if (encontrado==true){
    this.color=color;
    } else{
    this.color=COLORCONST;
    }
    }
}

public float precioFinal(){
    float aumento=0;
    switch (this.consumo){
        case 'a':
            aumento=aumento+100;
            break;
        case 'b':
            aumento+=80;
            break;
        case 'c':
            aumento+=60;
            break;
        case 'd':
            aumento+=50;
            break;
        case 'e':
            aumento+=30;
            break;
        case 'f':
            aumento+=10;
            break;
    }
    if ((this.peso>=0)&&(this.peso<19)){
        aumento+=10;
    }
    if ((this.peso>=20)&&(this.peso<49)){
        aumento+=50;
    }
    if ((this.peso>=50)&&(this.peso<79)){
        aumento+=80;
    }
    if (this.peso>=80){
        aumento+=100;
    }
    return this.precioBase+aumento;
    
}}
```

Clase Lavarropas

```
public class Lavarropas extends Electrodomestico{
private final static float CARGACONST=5;
private float carga;

public Lavarropas(){
    super();
}
public Lavarropas(float precio, float peso){
    super(precio,peso);
}

public Lavarropas(float carga, float precioBase, String color, char consumo, float peso) {
    super(precioBase, color, consumo, peso);
    this.carga = carga;
}


public float getCarga() {
    return carga;
}

public float precioFinal(){
    float plusCarga=super.precioFinal();
    if (this.carga>30){
        plusCarga+=50;
    }
    return plusCarga;
}}
```

Comment: Si ya estás seguro de que la clase es una instancia de Lavarropas porque entró al `if` entonces haz un cast dentro del `if`. Por ejemplo, dentro del if podríás escribir: `Lavarropas temp = (Lavarropas) listaElectro[i];` y ya luego accedes al método que quieras del objeto llamando por ejemplo `temp.getCarga()`.

Comment: Por cierto, aunque sea mas o menos el mismo problema, nada que ver las clases que describes (Asalariaado, EmpleadoProd, EmpleadoDistrib) con las que pones en tu codigo(Electrodomestico, Lavarropas, Television). Te recomendaría ser más consistente en tus futuras preguntas.

Comment: Hola Jaime, primero gracias por tu respuesta. Sí es verdad, estoy mezclando 2 ejercicios similares, perdón!

Comment: Probé lo que me indicas pero paraece que no está filtrando el if. Declaro una variable de tipo Lavarropas y me da erroe de que no coinciden los tipos, la declaado como Electrodomestico y sí puedo hacer la asignación, así que el tema está en la condición del if que no me discrimina.

Comment: Yo la verdad veo que la solucion que intenta quien formula la pregunta, combinada con la sugerencia de @JaimeMenéndez funciona. Pero, todo si realmente son subclases. Asi que para poder contrastar se necesita el fuente de las declaracuones de las clases`Electrodomestico`, `Lavadora` y `Television`

Comment: que significan cada uno de los valores ue le pasas en los constructores? para que quieres acceder a la carga?

Comment: @RuslanLópez porque el ejercicio me pide que si se cumple otra condición más muestre un dato de esa clase.

Comment: puedes agregar cual es esa condicion? porque a como tienes tu codigo basta con `float carga=((Lavarropas)(listaElectro[i])).getCarga();`

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Electrodomestico {

protected final static String COLORCONST="Blanco";
protected final static char CONSUMOCONST='f';
protected final float PRECIOCONST=100;
protected final static float PESOCONST=5;

protected float precioBase;
protected String color;
protected char consumo;
protected float peso;

public Electrodomestico() {
}

public Electrodomestico(float precioBase, float peso) {
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
    this.peso = peso;
}

public Electrodomestico(float precioBase, String color, char consumo, float peso) {
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
    this.color = color;
    this.consumo = consumo;
    this.peso = peso;
}
 public float getPrecioBase() {
    return precioBase;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public float getConsumo() {
    return consumo;
}

public float getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

private void comprobarConsumoEnergetico(char letra){
    if ((letra>65 && letra<71)||(letra>97 && letra<102)){
            this.consumo=letra;
    }
            else{
                    this.consumo=CONSUMOCONST;
            }
}

private void comprobarColor(String color){
    String vectColor[]={"blanco", "negro", "rojo", "azul", "gris"};
    boolean encontrado=false;
    for (int i=0; i<vectColor.length && encontrado==true; i++) {
        if (color.equals(vectColor[i])){
            encontrado=true;
        }
    if (encontrado==true){
    this.color=color;
    } else{
    this.color=COLORCONST;
    }
    }
}

public float precioFinal(){
    float aumento=0;
    switch (this.consumo){
        case 'a':
            aumento=aumento+100;
            break;
        case 'b':
            aumento+=80;
            break;
        case 'c':
            aumento+=60;
            break;
        case 'd':
            aumento+=50;
            break;
        case 'e':
            aumento+=30;
            break;
        case 'f':
            aumento+=10;
            break;
    }
    if ((this.peso>=0)&&(this.peso<19)){
        aumento+=10;
    }
    if ((this.peso>=20)&&(this.peso<49)){
        aumento+=50;
    }
    if ((this.peso>=50)&&(this.peso<79)){
        aumento+=80;
    }
    if (this.peso>=80){
        aumento+=100;
    }
    return this.precioBase+aumento;
    
}}
```

Clase Lavarropas

```
public class Lavarropas extends Electrodomestico{
private final static float CARGACONST=5;
private float carga;

public Lavarropas(){
    super();
}
public Lavarropas(float precio, float peso){
    super(precio,peso);
}

public Lavarropas(float carga, float precioBase, String color, char consumo, float peso) {
    super(precioBase, color, consumo, peso);
    this.carga = carga;
}


public float getCarga() {
    return carga;
}

public float precioFinal(){
    float plusCarga=super.precioFinal();
    if (this.carga>30){
        plusCarga+=50;
    }
    return plusCarga;
}}
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o una edición de tu pregunta?